# PHP cannot echo full response after submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After submit my form, php store data at sql well. but cannot sent full data echo at Jquery response.

See my code here I mention below which data not echo after submit, but after page refresh its show well.

```
echo'
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>'.$company.' at '.$city.'<br>';

// below this 2 line not show at update
if($running == '1' && $ayear != '0000'){ echo'Since '.$ayear.'';}
if($ayear != '0000' && $byear != '0000' && $running == '0'){ echo 'Year: '.$ayear.' to '.$byear.'';}

echo '  </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
```

ajax submit:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "../about", cache: false,
        data: "action=work&aaa="+ aaw + "&bbb="+ bbw + "&ccc="+ ccw + "&ddd="+ ddw + "&eee="+ eew + "&fff="+ ffw + "&ggg="+ ggw + "&mmm="+ mmw,
        success: function(response){
            if (response != 'error') {
            $('#oldwork'+ mmw).hide();
            $('#editwork'+ mmw).fadeIn().html(response);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: PHP : json_encode() and AJAX : DataType: 'json'. You should work with objects and append the response directly with jQuery